# Assign Custom Property to substring of another Property in SOAP UI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm trying to assign one Custom Property to a piece of another another in the SOAP UI Custom Properties dialog and not having much luck. I simplified my example:

[image: SOAP UI Custom Properties]

The above doesn't work, but also doesn't generate any errors?

The following works, but seems really heavy-handed:

`${=context.expand( '${#Project#ENV}' ).substring(7)}` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are combining property expansion with a Groovy script incorrectly.

`${#Project#ENV}` will always expand to a String. You can then call a Groovy method that is extended from String. But you need to tell SoapUI that you are calling a Groovy method. This is done with `${= ... }`. So your final expansion should look like:

```
${= '${#Project#ENV}'.subString(7) }
```

Additional information in [official docs](https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/property-expansion.html).